# MKMapView showsuserlocation

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, userlocation

In my app I have a rare bug that stops showing the userlocation.  If I tone the app down and just have the map, and set everything up in the viewDidLoad, and at the end do the typical:

```
myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

everything works great 99% of the time.  It always works when the App is starting from scratch, but like 1 time out of 100, when resuming from the background, the userlocation doesn't show.  And even if I make a button to turn showsUserLocation back on, it still won't show (and upon doing NSLog's the property shows that it is set to YES in the MKMapView).  If I kill the program, and start it again, it works fine again.

Everything is being done in the main thread as well.

Anyone encounter anything like this?

Comment: I've seen this as well. I assume that this happens when gps does not send location updates to the app, and thus MKMapView does not update the user location - if it happens not to be currently visible, it will not be drawn. But I might as well be completely wrong and it is a bug.

Comment: The strange thing is I can background the app a bunch of times, but when it comes back to the foreground, once it messes up and doesn't show, it will NEVER show.  Until I close the app and restart it anyways.

Comment: It sounds like your mapview's delegate is being cleared. Probably a memory event was triggered, and the delegate isn't being set properly on resume.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this image for fetch location in backgroud Mode

[image]